# Font-face trouble (sharp edges) in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, font-face

I'm using this font:

https://material.io/guidelines/resources/roboto-noto-fonts.html

(`Roboto-Regular.ttf` and `Roboto-Medium.ttf`)

and in `css` (less) i define `@font-face` this way:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  src: url('Roboto-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto-Medium';
  src: url('Roboto-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

later i use it so:

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.some-element {
  font: 2.2rem 'Roboto';
}
```

and in every browser, except `Firefox` and `IE` is ok.

in those browsers i got:

[image]

in Chrome everything is fine:

[image]

edges aren't smooth, i don't know, why? what i do wrong?
btw: i cannot use google-fonts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason, that font doesn't seem optimized for the web, even though the material page says *"The latest version of Roboto is designed for both mobile and web usage."*

However, there are free services that will convert a TTF font to a general webfont, like [Font Squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). I used that tool to convert the "Roboto Regular" font to a webfont and it looks fine. I setup a demo for you, but since that requires hosting a file, I put the demo on my personal website - http://www.mcoker.com/font/

So you could use that tool to create a webfont package for each of the Roboto fonts you want to use... however, unless you have a specific reason to host that webfont yourself, I would just use Google Fonts CDN.

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-size: large;
}
.some-element {
  font-size: 5em;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500" rel="stylesheet">
<p class="some-element">foo bar</p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut enim vitae arcu vestibulum eleifend. Quisque leo mi, facilisis sed massa non, cursus ornare tortor. Integer sem magna, porttitor at dui at, pharetra iaculis risus. Aliquam at viverra velit. Morbi condimentum, elit eu ultricies imperdiet, elit urna vulputate urna, a commodo lacus est in lorem. Donec ultricies hendrerit volutpat. Donec arcu nisl, rhoncus et auctor convallis, cursus sit amet nisl. Vivamus laoreet augue id congue sollicitudin. </p>
```

Comment: this tool is craching my line-height & Cyrillic chars

Answer (score 0):

directly using font will not be compatible in all browsers so you should generate web fonts using below-mentioned link[enter link description here](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

then add all generated files inside fonts folder(url('font/FrescoInfSans-SemiBold.woff')), Please see the example in snippet.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto-Medium';
  src: url('font/Roboto-Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  url('font/Roboto-Medium.woff') format('woff'), url('font/Roboto-Medium.ttf')  format('truetype'), url('font/Roboto-Medium.svg#Roboto-Medium') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
h1{font-family 'Roboto-Medium';}
```

```html
<h1>Hello Testing Font</h1>
```